# Scaffold dbcontext with owned types SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, scaffolding

I want to do scaffold-dbcontext in an MVC app using .net core 3.1 to SQL Server. The issue is that this database has owned types of SQL fields, so when I tried to use Scaffold-DBContext it doesn't work

```
Scaffold-DbContext "mystringconnection" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

It is possible to scaffold owned types SQL Server using EF Core?

Comment: What do you mean by "owned types of SQL fields"?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean

Comment: What is what you mean?  "owned type" is not a term that means anything in SQL Server.

Comment: I mean that "owned type" is that for example in your SQL you have a varchar, it appears as "multivar" and in owned types you set the relationship